# What's the use case of method parameter attributes?

Tags: c#, parameters, attributes

Putting in Equals and hashcode overrides I had the NotNullWhen attribute autocomplete when making the method - reading the documentation my understanding is that it basically says that when Equals returns true, the parameter obj being fed in will not be null. Why would I ever want to have this attribute? This is sitting in a struct which can't be null, and the override wouldn't allow for a null parameter to ever return true anyway. Does having this attribute really matter at all? It's not enforcing that logic either right?

```
public override bool Equals([NotNullWhen(true)] object? obj)
        {
            return (obj is Time time && Hour == time.Hour && Minute == time.Minute);
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Method parameter attributes, writ large, have a number of uses. For example, they can be used to direct web frameworks to populate the parameter by serializing the body of an HTTP request. [Some](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.callerargumentexpressionattribute?view=net-7.0) will direct the compiler to automatically provide a value for an optional parameter in cases where none is explicitly provided.

Attributes like the one in your example are designed to make life easier for the *consumer* of your method. For example, if someone uses your class like this:

```
Time? providedTime = GetTimeFromInputs();
if(targetTime.Equals(providedTime))
{
    DoSomethingWith(providedTime.Hour, providedTime.Minute)
}
```

Without the attribute on the Equals method, the C# compiler and analyzers will very helpfully warn the developer that `providedTime.Hour` might throw a null reference exception. The developer might intuitively know there's no way that could happen when `Equals` returned true, but the IDE still gives them an annoying little yellow squiggly. With the attribute in place, the compiler knows enough not to give you that false warning.